# Weights and Bias from Trained Meta Graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, protoc

I have successfully exported a re-trained InceptionV3 NN as a TensorFlow meta graph. I have read this protobuf back into python successfully, but I am struggling to see a way to export each layers weight and bias values, which I am assuming is stored within the meta graph protobuf, for recreating the nn outside of TensorFlow.

My workflow is as such:

```
Retrain final layer for new categories
Export meta graph tf.train.export_meta_graph(filename='model.meta')
Build python pb2.py using Protoc and meta_graph.proto
Load Protobuf:

import meta_graph_pb2
saved = meta_graph_pb2.CollectionDef()
with open('model.meta', 'rb') as f:
  saved.ParseFromString(f.read())
```

From here I can view most aspects of the graph, like node names and such, but I think my inexperience is making it difficult to track down the correct way to access the weight and bias values for each relevant layer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `MetaGraphDef` proto doesn't actually contain the values of the weights and biases. Instead it provides a way to associate a `GraphDef` with the weights stored in one or more checkpoint files, written by a [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver). The [`MetaGraphDef` tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/meta_graph/index.html) has more details, but the approximate structure is as follows:

1. In you training program, write out a checkpoint using a `tf.train.Saver`. This will also write a `MetaGraphDef` to a `.meta` file in the same directory.

   ```
   saver = tf.train.Saver(...)
   # ...
   saver.save(sess, "model")
   ```

   You should find files called `model.meta` and `model-NNNN` (for some integer `NNNN`) in your checkpoint directory.
2. In another program, you can import the `MetaGraphDef` you just created, and restore from a checkpoint.

   ```
   saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("model.meta")
   saver.restore("model-NNNN")  # Or whatever checkpoint filename was written.
   ```

   If you want to get the value of each variable, you can (for example) find the variable in `tf.all_variables()` collection and pass it to `sess.run()` to get its value. For example, to print the values of all variables, you can do the following:

   ```
   for var in tf.all_variables():
     print var.name, sess.run(var)
   ```

   You could also filter `tf.all_variables()` to find the particular weights and biases that you're trying to extract from the model.

Comment: Thank you, this is a huge help. I am attempting to recreate a trained network and deploy it like this new [iOS example](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/MetalImageRecognition/Introduction/Intro.html). Given your expertise, is this the right way to go about establishing the network parameters (binary .dat files for each layer's weight and bias as arrays of floats) ? End goal will be a TensorFlow trained network, inference on Metal.

Comment: Hmm, it depends on how complex the network is. You might be able to go straight to the checkpoint (e.g. using `tf.train.NewCheckpointReader()`) and read out NumPy arrays from the checkpoint file, bypassing the `MetaGraphDef`. Indeed you might even be able to use the C++ implementation of the `CheckpointReader` in your iOS program, if you are able to link it in (though I'm not sure how difficult that linking would be).

Comment: The `tf.train.NewCheckpointReader()` is a wonderful API. I loaded it with an inception_v3 checkpoint hoping to recreate the arrays stored in the aforementioned dat files. There is a disconnect for me as to how they are producing their network parameters. They load in 190 files (1 bias, 1 weight file for each node) as network parameters, yet TF has over 1200 stored variables for the inception model. Any pointers to bridge the gap?